# Reading console Char input in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I don't know how to get a char as input

fun main(args:Array){

}

in my kotlin code the problem is (compareto(0) which is not allowed on a nullablereciever "n"

Comment: Could you show your code that includes the error?

Comment: fun main(args :Array<String>){
   print("enter a charecter")
    var c:Char=readLine()!!.toChar}
i don't know how to get a Character as input in kotlin

Answer (score 5):

It is possible with java.util.Scanner. It reads anything before space or line break, then converts it to character

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val chr = scanner.next().single()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can get Char input by using `read()` method of the `System` class.

```
System.`in`.read().toChar()
```

Here, `System.in.read()` returns ASCII value (Integer) of the Character entered by the user.
Then `toChar()` method converts the Integer value to Char.

Answer (score 0):

> fun readLine(): String? 
> Reads a line of input from the standard input
>   stream.

So you read a sequence of chars until you press Enter.
If you input 1 char only and then press Enter, [readLine()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) will return a `String` containing this char only.
In any case you can get the 1st char you entered as the 1st char of the `String` returned by `readLine()`:

```
print("enter a character")
val c = readLine()!![0]
```

If you press Enter without entering any char you will get a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

Answer (score 0):

print("enter a character")
val c = readLine()!!.first

in this case we read the first character from Line

Answer (score 0):

print("Enter the character: "); val c = readLine()!!.single()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simple `readln()` method might be used (from Kotlin 1.6)

```
val answer = readln().single()
```